# Form fields not visible after creating content fields using A&M Forms plugin

Tags: form, field, craft2, plugin-amforms

I'm new to Craft 2, and I created about 20 new form fields in the Settings>Content>Fields section.  I created a new group for them to go in.

Then, I went to create a new Form, but I cannot see those new form fields.

Is there a way to see them?  Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you are creating a new form? Did you create a section for form entries?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, our website has the Forms (1.7.0) plugin by A&M Impact.  In the left hand navigation in admin, there is a 'Forms' link, with a sublink for 'submissions,' 'forms,' etc.  I click on the 'forms' sublink and construct a form, and there is a 'fields' tab, which I click.  The page I see has 6 'fieldsets,' but there are none of the fields I created in 'settings>content>fields.'  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [noted in the documentation for AM Forms](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms#fields) the fields that are created for forms

> …are stored in a different context / scope than Craft's fields.

and that;

> …they won't be shown in Craft's field list.

I *assume* that the reverse is then also true, so fields created in Craft will not be visible in the plugin.